# How to stop the iteration of a forEach inside another forEach?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach

```
arr1.forEach(function(){
 arr2.forEach(function(){
   if(some condition true){
    return; // this only skips the arr2 functionality
   }
   // rest of the code

 });
});
```

return only stops functionality. I want it to stop the whole arr2 iteration and continue the arr1 iteration?

**UPDATE:**
(PS: Already know I can get a variable and make it true so the rest of the loop will iterate but wont do anything. )

break and continue gives this error
Cannot determine target for 'break/continue '

Comment: Can you show the data you have and what you're trying to achieve? There's probably a better way to do this rather than nesting `forEach()` methods

Comment: You cannot - `.forEach` will iterate through all elements. If you need to stop, then you might need a `for`/`for...of` loop.

Comment: Replace `forEach` with `every` and `return true` to continue and `return false` to stop.

Comment: @kemicofa can you provide a sample?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney   its bit complicatied show here. there are two kind of object arrays.

Comment: @VLAZ thanks :) just wanted to use forEach for clean code.